# iPhone NSURLSessionTask does not work on iOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios6, nsurlsessiontask

With the following code

```
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: localFilePath];
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL: url completionHandler:
                              ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
                              {
                                  self.avAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:data error: nil];
                                  self.avAudioPlayer.volume = 0.5;
                                  self.avAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
                                  [self.avAudioPlayer play];
                              }];
    [task resume];
```

Task never starts on iOS 6.x, but works fine with iOS 7.x, 8.x

Will be looking for another way of doing this, but curious by it is not work on iOS 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because, as [the official reference on `NSURLSessionTask`](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/index.html) states, it's been introduced in iOS 7.0.

Comment: Ha ok.  Thanks.  Just took it out and it the player works fine in this case.